# TCPDF draw circle with border and fill

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF in my php application, but I'm not finding a way to draw a circle with black border and filled with another color;

here my code:

```
$style_bollino = array('width' => 0.25, 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0));
$this->SetAlpha(1);
$this->Circle(35, 100, 4, 0, 360, 'C', $style_bollino, array(210, 0, 0));
```

I tried also to change 'C' parameter to 'F' or null but I didn't get the result.

I'm not able to figure out what I'm missing

kind regards,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

According to [one of their examples](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_012/), there's a one-liner way to do it, just pass `'DF'` to `$style` parameter:

```
$this->Circle(35, 100, 4, 0, 360, 'DF', $style_bollino, array(210, 0, 0));
```

For a list of options for this parameter, check the PHPDoc in `TCPDF_STATIC::getPathPaintOperator()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fairly straightforward requirement but I can't work out how to do it in one line either.

However, it's pretty simple to fill the circle and then draw another stroked circle on top of it.

```
foreach (array("F", "S") as $fill_style) {
    $this->Circle(35, 100, 4, 0, 360, $fill_style, $style_bollino, array(210, 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh.... thank you so much @Matt. I was so tired that I didn't think to a simple solution.